# Convergence in Metric spaces and Balls

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

im having a little doubt about convergence in metric spaces. So we know that for an arbitrary topological space a sequence of points converges to $x$ if corresponding to each neighborhood $U$ of $x$ there exists a natural number $N$ such that $x_n \in U$ for all $n \geq N$.

Obviously this applies to metric spaces. My question is that if we are in metric spaces to prove that a sequence converges to a points $x$ it is enough to prove that  for any Ball of radius $\epsilon >0$, $B_\epsilon$ there exists a natural number $N$ such that $x_n \in B_\epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$. I guess this can be generalized to basis elements, but yeah thats my question. This seems to be true to me but i am not really convinced, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: if $U$ is any open set containing $x$ then there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that $B(x,\epsilon) \subset U$.

Comment: Ok im thinking of doing this an an equality , so by the normal defintion we get that for Balls is true , now assume is true for balls we have that fact yeah i think we get that converges by the definition.